# java.lang.NullPointerException when resume activity in viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I would like to resume activity which i have stored in share preferences in viewpager. I have stored the activity details in onSaveState and retrieve the activity getpreferences in onResume. But somehow, it returns error that the key is in null value in onSaveState. How to save the preferences in viewpager ?

Here is the code

```
public class FullScreenImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
ImageView favBtn;
private SharedPreference sharedPreference;
Activity context = this;
private Fragment contentFragment;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image); //TBS
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("content")) {
        String content = savedInstanceState.getString("content");
        if (content.equals(FavouriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FavouriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
                contentFragment = fragmentManager
                        .findFragmentByTag(FavouriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            }
        }
    }

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
    String[] arr=i.getStringArrayExtra("array");
    String url = i.getStringExtra("url");

    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.slider);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new GalleryViewPagerAdapter(this, arr, position, url));
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);


}


class GalleryViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String[] imageArrayList;
    private String mUrl;
    private  int mPosition;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;


    public GalleryViewPagerAdapter(Context _context, String[] imageArrayList, int position, String url) {
        context = _context;
        this.imageArrayList = imageArrayList; //null;
        this.mPosition=position;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mUrl=url;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageArrayList.length;
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        showProgress();

        favBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_favourite);

        String favoriteUrl=sharedPreference.getPrefsFavUrl(context);
       //Boolean stateBtnNow=sharedPreference.getBtnState(context,mUrl);//why mUrl change to same url with favourite
        Boolean stateBtnNow=false;
        if(stateBtnNow) {
             favBtn.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 249, 0, 0));//red
         }
        else
         {
             favBtn.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 192, 192, 192));
         }

        favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Boolean stateBtn = sharedPreference.getBtnState(context, mUrl);
                Boolean stateBtn=false;
                if (!stateBtn) {
                    sharedPreference.save(context, mUrl);
                    //edit to save url in array
                    //sharepreference.add(context, product);
                    sharedPreference.saveBtnState(context, stateBtn);
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Added to Favourite!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    favBtn.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 249, 0, 0));//red
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Button state is " + stateBtn,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    sharedPreference.saveBtnState(context, stateBtn);
                    favBtn.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 192, 192, 192));//grey
                }


            }


        });

        View photoRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fullscreen_image, container,
                false);

        TouchImageView fullScreenImg;
        fullScreenImg =(TouchImageView)photoRow.findViewById(R.id.img_flickr);

       // added imageloader for better performance
        StaggeredDemoApplication.getImageLoader().get(imageArrayList[position],
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(fullScreenImg, R.drawable.bg_no_image, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert), container.getWidth(), 0);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(photoRow);
        stopProgress();

        return photoRow;

    }

    private void stopProgress() {

        mProgress.cancel();
    }

    private void showProgress() {
        mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(FullScreenImageActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }




}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("content", FavouriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

Here is the code in sharepreferences

```
public class SharedPreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "AOP_PREFS";
    public static final String PREFS_STATE="AOP_BTN";
    public static final String PREFS_FAV_URL="AOP_FAV_URL";

    public static final String PREFS_KEY = "AOP_PREFS_String";
    public static final String PREF_BTN_KEY = "AOP_PREF_BTN";
    public static final String PREF_URL_KEY = "AOP_PREF_URL";

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    public void save(Context context, String text) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;
        //edit here to add image array list

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
        editor = settings.edit(); //2
        editor.putString(PREFS_KEY, text); //3
        editor.commit(); //4

    }

    public String getValue(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        String text;

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        text = settings.getString(PREFS_KEY, null);

        return text;
    }

    public String getPrefsFavUrl(Context context){
        SharedPreferences settings;
        String favUrl;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FAV_URL, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        favUrl = settings.getString(PREF_URL_KEY, null);

        return favUrl;
    }

    public void clearSharedPreference(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void removeValue(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        editor.remove(PREFS_KEY);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void saveBtnState(Context context, Boolean stateBtn) {

        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_STATE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
        editor = settings.edit(); //2
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_BTN_KEY, stateBtn);//added state for button
        editor.commit(); //4

    }

    public boolean getBtnState(Context context,String text)//edit to store url here and check the boolean here
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs;
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String favUrl = getPrefsFavUrl(context);

        boolean switchState = false;

        if(favUrl.equals(text)) {
            switchState=true;
        }

        return switchState;

    }


    public void saveFavourite(FragmentActivity activity, String favouriteUrl) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        settings = activity.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FAV_URL, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
        editor = settings.edit(); //2
        editor.putString(PREF_URL_KEY, favouriteUrl); //3
        editor.commit(); //4
    }
}
```

Here is the error log file

```
02-03 09:48:57.928 15368-15368/com.example.myapp W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance()' on a null object reference
02-03 09:48:57.928 15368-15368/com.example.myapp W/System.err:     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.displayView(MainActivity.java:141)
02-03 09:48:57.928 15368-15368/com.example.myapp W/System.err:     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
02-03 09:48:57.928 15368-15368/com.example.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
```

Here is my MainActivity program

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentFlickrGridImage.OnFragmentInteractionListener, ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener {

    private int backstack_count;
    private boolean viewIsAtHome;
    private Fragment contentFragment;
    private ShareActionProvider share;
    private Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            displayView(R.id.recent_picture);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean isAddToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment);
        if (isAddToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().toString());
            backstack_count ++;
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
        share = new ShareActionProvider(this);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(item, share);

        return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.share) {
            onShareAction();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void onShareAction() {
        String yourShareText = "test";
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this).setType("text/plain").setText(yourShareText).getIntent();
        // Set the share Intent
        if (share != null) {
            share.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        displayView(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }

    private void displayView(int itemId) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;
        String title="";

        switch (itemId){
        case R.id.one:
            fragment = new FragmentFlickrGridImage("one");
            title="one";
            viewIsAtHome=true;
            break;
        case R.id.two:
            fragment = new FragmentFlickrGridImage(" two");
            title ="two";
            viewIsAtHome=false;
            break;
        case R.id.three:
            fragment = new FragmentFlickrGridImage("three");
            title="three";
            viewIsAtHome=false;
            break;

        case R.id.four:
            fragment=new FavouriteListFragment();
            title="Favourite";
            viewIsAtHome=false;
        break;
        }
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        if (!viewIsAtHome) { //if the current view is not the Recent Hot Girl fragment
           displayView(R.id.recent_picture);

        } else {

            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            //Yes button clicked
                            finish();
                            break;

                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                            //No button clicked
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setTitle("Exit");
            builder.show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source,
                                         Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, intent.getComponent().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's "MainActivity" ???

Comment: @LouisNguyen, i have added MainActivity, thank you!

Comment: @michelletbs how do you resume your instance? I can't find it anywhere in your pasted code.

Answer (score 0):

The error line is:

```
fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
```

`fragmentClass` is always assigned with `null` object when you use it in `fragmentClass.newInstance()`, and it always have `null` value because you never assign it with other value. Try to remove these lines:

```
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Anyway, using non-empty constructor for the fragments is not a good practice. You should use [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/3922207) instead.

---

**EDIT**

Check whether fragment is empty or not:

```
if (fragment != null){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: i guess becoz that app earns like hell

Comment: @ankitagrawal, i work for company, i not sure whether it can earn unless u have advertisment